# cannot add foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

Hello I want to create a foreign key to relate 2 tables but when I am using this query

```
ALTER TABLE Player
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_team_id FOREIGN KEY (team_id)
REFERENCES Team(id);
```

I get the error Error code: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

I am using a innoDB engine with utf8 encoding.. the tables Player and Team look like this

**Player**
id PK Auto_increment etc
..
..
team_id ( must be foreign key )

**Team**
id PK
..

Anyone got the solution for this?

Here is the create table syntax

```
    CREATE TABLE `Player` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Firstname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Prefix` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Age` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Position` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Caps` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Goals` tinyint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Captain` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE `Team` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Coach` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Prefix` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: are your tables already populated with data ?

Comment: What are the types and display lengths of the fields you mentioned and what Herode said - did you populate them with data?

Comment: Answering would be easier if you show the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE Player and SHOW CREATE TABLE Team.

Comment: they are not populated with data yet. is this what causes the problem?

Comment: After adding data it gives the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the two columns are identical (`SIGNED`, `NULL`able, etc.). Also, any values that are being referenced must exist in the referenced table. Otherwise, run `SHOW INNODB STATUS` after attempting to create the key for further information.

Comment: @Reshad `int(11) DEFAULT NULL` is not the same as `int(11) unsigned NOT NULL`

Comment: check my post please i've added the create syntax of the tables

Comment: @Reshad They must be **identical** (other than the name)

Answer (score 0):

There are two main reasons why the contraint couldn't be added.

The first (and most likely) is that there is one or more team_id's data in the Player table that does not exist in the Team table.

The second is if the data types of the two tables are different.

Run the following query to see if there is a problem with the team id's in the player table:

```
select team_id
from Player
where team_id not in (select id from team)
```

Essentially that will identify team_ids that are missing.  Fix as necessary.  One thing to look for is a team_id in the player table of -1 or 0 (whatever your default is) which is not represented in the team table.